# What to use when cookies are disabled

Tags: php, authentication, session-cookies

I am creating a simple site and am a little stuck on what to do for my users if their cookies are disabled. If one is to login and left idle for a couple minutes how would I keep that user logged in and identified if their cookies are disabled?

Comment: Cookies are the standard way to maintain sessions. Very few people disable them and it is not unreasonable to ask people who do to allow your site to set them if they want to log in.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll — That lets the session token leak when people share URLs with friends, and become stale when they bookmark pages.

Comment: As an exercise, you could use $_POST or $_GET to send a session id to be compared with the database on the server.  But in general I agree with Quentin's comment.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, I know, but if disabled cookies is really an issue it's one of only 2 or 3 ways I can think of to get around it. The other would be sending the session id as an HTTP request/response header, but that exposes the same issue.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll: session IDs in urls is a massive security hole. it'll leak to external sites via http referer, show up in the server's access log, etc...

Comment: @MarcB I completely agree, and I've already mentioned another alternative in a subsequent comment, but I don't think the alternative is necessarily more secure. What would you do?

Comment: @BrianDriscoll: probably tell the user "no cookies, no logins". I fully support disabling 3rd party cookies to prevent ad network tracking, but there's no reason to be disabling 1st party cookies, especially since it disables so much "standard" web functionality.

Comment: @seanr, how badly do you want users that don't have cookies enabled? The work-arounds are weak, difficult and hackable. They're a lot of work, so you'll need to ask yourself if it's worth it.

Answer (score 1):

If cookies are blocked, your options are:

1. Pass the session ID in the URL as a parameter.
2. Embed the session ID in the page (in a hidden element, of course), and refer to it using JavaScript.

As a side note, recently I've seen several sites saying that my browsing experience would be severely limited, as long as cookies are disabled in my browser. Depending on how much I need the site's function, I'll either enable cookies, use a different browser with cookies enabled, or decide to skip the site altogether.

Comment: `Pass the session ID in the URL as a parameter` can be a security risk as the URL could be sent in a `referer` header by the browser and leak the Session ID. It will also be stored in browser history, proxy and server logs by default.

Comment: Workarounds, by their very nature, are more dangerous. But if you manage sessions well, make them temporary, and maybe tied to the initial IP, you can mitigate the risk some.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that works in modern browsers is to utilize [Web Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). This is also suggested as a preferred [replacement to cookies](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#introduction). ([browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=webstorage))
First check if cookies or Web Storage is available in the browser, use which you prefer to set your values to check there. You could then fall back to the hidden session data that @TravelingTechGuy suggested, then from there you could ask your users to comply or restrict access.

I agree that session data in the URL isn't a good idea for the reasons mentioned in comments to the OP.

The only downside (that I can think of ATM) to the "on page hidden session data" would be potentially back end "session leak" in code. You wouldn't want to accidentally send back a wrong session ID to the client in HTML since you have to persist that data in the page by sending it to the server and back each time (unless you utilize some single page app style to keep that session data local only). Preferably you only want to check a submitted session ID and react from there.

If you suspect you may lose user base that may impact your service because of some restriction, it would be best to try and provide as many checks and fallbacks as possible.

Answer (score -1):

You could have a try on Flash cookies. If you get a copy of Flash 5, it works without permission (it wasn't even documentated, but it works). It would really be a dirty hack though.